# Finding last entered input

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="1" readonly="">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="2" readonly="">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="3" readonly="">
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" value="" readonly="">
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the last entered input:

```
document.querySelector('.input-pin input[value!=""]:last-child')
```

... so `last-child` of input with value `not empty`, but its an invalid selector.

Comment: How do you define "*…the last entered input*"? Is it the last input element, the last one without a non–empty *value* attribute (i.e. value attribute !== "") or the last one with a non–empty *value* property (i.e. value property !== "")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to base the selection on the attribute value, then you could use the `:not()` pseudo class to negate the input element with an empty value.

In this case the selector would be:

```
input[value]:not([value=""])
```

From there, you can select all the matching elements and retrieve the last one:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[value]:not([value=""])');
var lastInputWithValue = inputs[inputs.length - 1];
```

...or:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[value]:not([value=""])');
var lastInputWithValue = Array.from(inputs).pop();
```

---

If the value can change and you want to check based on current property value (rather than the attribute value), then you would need to filter the elements:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var lastInputWithValue = Array.from(inputs).filter(i => i.value).pop();
```

---

As a side note, the `:last-child` pseudo class will only return the last child element inside of the parent element based on their order. It will not filter the selected elements and select the last one by their attribute or class as you are expecting. Also, `[value!=""]` is not a valid attribute selector as you pointed out. However, you can use `input[value]:not([value=""])` like I pointed out above.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply do `document.querySelector('.input-group input:last-child');`